# Big difference between chrome view vs print preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

How do I print what I actually see on Chrome?  The print preview looks to be lacking the font, shaded alternate row coloring and font size.  Here is the chrome output

[image: Chrome] "Chrome"

Here is the print previw

[image: Print Preview] "Print Preview"

The HTML behind this page:
http://textuploader.com/xc9t

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a css to use for print. Please take a look at media queries

http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_mediatypes.asp

Comment: For the bootstrap css, I have them as media=print or media=all but I still get the attached screenshot result

Comment: Hmm, do you mind sharing a snippet of your css, I can take a look and see what might be causing this.

Comment: Hi, it seems like the snippet you provided is not formatted properly. There's some missing tags. Please ensure you are providing me the proper code snippet.

Comment: http://textuploader.com/xc9t  
Try here, Copy and Paste truncates on here for some reason